# Is there any documentation for how to implement barcodes in xforms

Tags: pdf, xhtml, xforms, orbeon

Please clarify how to implement barcode functionality within orbeon 3.9 PE.

The wiki reference (see link) isn't clear on how to implement.

http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-PDF-and-barcode

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with barcodes? The oxf.fr.detail.pdf.barcode property documented on the wiki just places a barcode with the document id on generated PDF. Do you need this, or something else?

Comment: @ebruchez we are trying to generate barcodes to template pdf's. We would also like to manipulate the barcode values to data values from form values.

Answer (score 1):

If you set this property the barcode should appear on the PDF.

```
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.detail.pdf.barcode.*.*" value="true"/>
```

This uses the document id as value for the barcode.

This is the only built-in function right now. You can see how this is done in the source here:

https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/fr/print/print-pdf-template.xsl

Comment: we have set this property to "true" and the barcode does not appear on the form

Comment: @andyg, this now fixed, and the fix is in the latest PE nightly. It was the usual unfortunate story: we introduced a new functionality, which broke this. If you don't want to get an entirely new build, you could just modify the version you have, applying this change: http://goo.gl/3u208. Now, this is a feature that we'd like to improve to allow you to control where the barcode is added in the PDF. Right now, it is always added at the bottom, at a fixed coordinate. For reference, the bug is: http://goo.gl/tM4VA.